# Arduino code not working

Tags: c++, temperature-sensor

Basically its an arduino project in which i am using an analog temperature sensor ky 013. The sensor is reading the temperatures correctly but what i want is to print the temperatures showed on the serial monitor to a lcd screen. I did the wiring and everything correctly  but there is something wrong with the code which i couldnt figure out. 
Here is the code.

```
#include <math.h>

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd = LiquidCrystal(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int sensorPin = A0; 
int switchState=0;



double Thermistor(int RawADC) 
{
    double Temp;
    Temp = log(((10240000/RawADC) - 10000));
    Temp = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp ))* Temp );
    Temp = Temp - 273.15;           
    return Temp;
}

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    pinMode(sensorPin,INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{

 switchState=digitalRead(sensorPin);
 int readVal=analogRead(sensorPin);
 double temp =  Thermistor(readVal);
 Serial.print("Temp. : ");
 Serial.print(temp); 
 Serial.println(" Celsius");
 lcd.clear();
 lcd.setCursor(0,0);
 lcd.print("Temp: ");
 lcd.print(temp);
 lcd.print(" C");
 delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Please *edit* your post and format the code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Comment: You haven't actually said *what's wrong*. If we don't know what's happening, we can't tell you why happening.

Comment: Have you checked if the pin defining is right for the LCD?

Comment: Does the lcd show "Temp: " as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Please format your code.  I know it takes longer, but the payoff is in readability and maintainability.  It's well worth the extra effort.

```
LiquidCrystal lcd = LiquidCrystal(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int sensorPin = A0;
int switchState = 0;

double Thermistor(int RawADC)
{
    double Temp;
    Temp = log(((10240000 / RawADC) - 10000));
    Temp = 1 / (0.001129148 + (0.000234125 + (0.0000000876741 * Temp * Temp)) * Temp);
    Temp = Temp - 273.15;
    return Temp;
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
    pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    switchState = digitalRead(sensorPin);
    int readVal = analogRead(sensorPin);
    double temp = Thermistor(readVal);
    Serial.print("Temp. : ");
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.println(" Celsius");
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Temp: ");
    lcd.print(temp);
    lcd.print(" C");
    delay(500);
}
```

I think the problem is the

```
lcd.print(temp);
```

Try casting it to a float from a double (and two decimal places).  Maybe you just need the decimal places.

```
lcd.print((float)temp, 2);
```